# Generate a list of objects using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have seen some somewhat similar questions but continuing to have trouble making this work. Let's say I want to generate a list of objects that I can plug into another loop function. something like:

`list=[y[0],y[1],y[2]]`

But the size of this list should vary depending on the length of y, which varies. If y consists of 100 objects the list should look like:

`list=[y[0],y[1],y[2]...y[99]]`

I have tried the following:

```
ylist=[]
k=len(y)
for r in range(1,k+1):
    yn="y"+"["+str(r)+"]"
    ylist.append(yn)
```

Which gives me:

```
['y[1]', 'y[2]', 'y[3]', 'y[4]', 'y[5]', 'y[6]', 'y[7]', 'y[8]', 'y[9]', 'y[10]']
```

but this does not seem to work in other functions the same way as 'list' above. I have tried converting into a string, but this does not work in other functions correctly either, I'm guessing because it is not a list anymore. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `y`? Why not just use `y` directly?

Comment: What is `y`? You seem to be grabbing an index, so it already seems to be iterable (in which case you can just do `list(y)`).

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Please provide a [mcve] with *expected output and input*. What does "but this does not seem to work in other functions the same way as 'list' above"??? None of what you are saying really makes sense because you are leaving out key details about *what you expect* and *what you are working with*

Answer (score -1):

I think that may help you

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
list1=[y[0],y[1],y[2]]
list2=[y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3]]

ylist=[]
k=len(y)
for r in range(1,k+1):
    yn="y"+"["+str(r)+"]"
    val=list(yn)
    ylist.append(val)
p=3
print(ylist,y[1:p])
#
```

Comment: While this does answer the question in exactly the way the user is asking for by adding the needed `eval()`. It is better to understand the underlying problem first, what you have presented looks as if it tries to deliberately be bad code. Why not just do `list(y)`?

Comment: yeah i thought  helping him to use it in all cases for int and float and lists conversions.. but you are right thanks a lot i must be specific, not general.eval can be dangerous it just for testing i understand